# StringTokenizer - first string?

Tags: java

I have this code to parse url string such as "?var=val"
but when "search" is just "var=val" this code fails, how to make just "var=val" work as well?

```
    StringTokenizer st1 =
    new StringTokenizer(search, "?&;");
    while(st1.hasMoreTokens()){
        String st2= st1.nextToken();

        int ii = st2.indexOf("=");
        if (ii > 0) {
            int ib = st2.length();
            myparms.put( st2.substring(0,ii) , st2.substring(ii+1,ib) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, that code *doesn't* fail. Could you provide a SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org) that shows how it fails?

Comment: This works for me too. if poss provide the err.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (search.charAt(0)!= '?') search = "?"+search;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, `StringTokenizer` has been deprecated and is only included now as a legacy class, you should take a look at [`String.split()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), instead.

Comment: StringTokenizer not deprecated still, but its usage is not encouraged.